# Check Status Of All Orders In a Deal And Mark Deal as Completed

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach, eloquent, laravel-relations

work_orders is hasMany() relationship.

```
foreach ($deal->work_orders as  $work_order) {
            if ($work_order->status != completed) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                completeDeal($deal->id);
            }
        }
```

I want to check If All Of the Orders in a deal are completed then run a function to complete a deal. If any of work orders is not completed Then Just Do nothing and return back.
Issue with my current code is that If any of the work order is completed it marks deal complete.
But I want to check if all order are completed

Answer (score 0):

You can do something link bellow

```
foreach ($deals as $key => $deal) {
       $total_order_count = $deal->work_orders->count();
       $completed_order_count = $deal->work_orders->where('status', 1)->count();
        if ($total_order_count != $completed_order_count ) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            completeDeal($deal->id);
        }
    }
```

Of Course you can optimize queries your self because for some reason my debugbar is not working.

Comment: Thanks...I did this when I got no answer...But issue is this code looks long...is there a way to make this short?

Comment: you can reference this for optimizing queries https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJe1OUDCOmY